# Bug in Scikit-Learn PCA or in Numpy Eigen Decomposition?

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, linear-algebra, pca

I have a dataset with 400 features.

What I did:

```
# approach 1
d_cov = np.cov(d_train.transpose())
eigens, mypca = LA.eig(d_cov) # assume sort by eigen value also/ LA = numpy linear algebra

# approach 2 
pca = PCA(n_components=300)
d_fit = pca.fit_transform(d_train)
pc = pca.components_
```

Now, these two should be the same, right? as PCA is just the eigendecomposition of the covariance matrix.

But these are very different in my case?

How could that be, I am doing any mistake above?

Comparing variances:

```
import numpy as np
LA = np.linalg
d_train = np.random.randn(100, 10)
d_cov = np.cov(d_train.transpose())
eigens, mypca = LA.eig(d_cov)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca =  PCA(n_components=10)
d_fit = pca.fit_transform(d_train)
pc = pca.components_
ve = pca.explained_variance_
#mypca[0,:], pc[0,:] pc.transpose()[0,:]

plt.plot(list(range(len(eigens))), [ x.transpose().dot(d_cov).dot(x) for x,y  in zip(mypca, eigens) ])
plt.plot(list(range(len(ve))), ve)
plt.show()

print(mypca, '\n---\n' , pc)
```

Comment: Could you please show your import statements?

Comment: Have you tried `pc.transpose()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In sklearn.decomposition.PCA, why are components\_ negative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44765682/in-sklearn-decomposition-pca-why-are-components-negative)

Comment: @P.Camilleri but even the variances are not the same? At least variances explained by the PCs and the eigenvectors should be the sam, right? Please see the edit.

Comment: FYI, use pc.T instead of pc.transpose(), it's shorter and you avoid creating a new array

Comment: The variances are the same, it lust be a bug in your code

Comment: @P.Camilleri no, i have used the same formula xTCx for variance along a vector x, where C is the covariance matrix

Comment: you are iterating over rows when you should iterate over coluns. See my answer.

Comment: @P.Camilleri, there's no difference between what `pc.T` produces and what `pc.transpose()` does.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the doc more carefully. numpy's doc is great and very thorough, very often you'll find the solution to your problem only by reading it.

Here is a modified version of your code (import on top of snippet, use of .T instead of .transpose(), pep8.)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

from numpy import linalg as LA

d_train = np.random.randn(100, 10)
d_cov = np.cov(d_train.transpose())
eigens, mypca = LA.eig(d_cov)

pca = PCA(n_components=10)
d_fit = pca.fit_transform(d_train)
pc = pca.components_
explained = pca.explained_variance_

my_explained = np.sort([x.T.dot(d_cov).dot(x) for x in mypca.T])[::-1]

plt.close('all')
plt.figure()
plt.plot(my_explained, label='me')
plt.plot(explained, label='sklearn')
plt.legend()
plt.show(block=False)
```

The two curves are exactly the same.
The important thing is that I iterate over my_pca.T, not my_pca.

```
Signature: np.linalg.eig(a)
Docstring:
Compute the eigenvalues and right eigenvectors of a square array.

Parameters
----------
a : (..., M, M) array
    Matrices for which the eigenvalues and right eigenvectors will
    be computed

Returns
-------
w : (..., M) array
    # not important for you

v : (..., M, M) array
    The normalized (unit "length") eigenvectors, such that the
    column ``v[:,i]`` is the eigenvector corresponding to the
    eigenvalue ``w[i]``.
```

The eigenvectors are returned as columns of `my_pca`, not rows. `for x in my_pca` was iterating over rows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on PCA but I seem to get similar values if I transpose one of the matrices.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> LA = np.linalg
>>> d_train = np.random.randn(100, 10)
>>> d_cov = np.cov(d_train.transpose())
>>> eigens, mypca = LA.eig(d_cov)
>>> from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
>>> pca =  PCA(n_components=10)
>>> d_fit = pca.fit_transform(d_train)
>>> pc = pca.components_
>>> mypca[0,:]
array([-0.44255435, -0.77430549, -0.14479638, -0.06459874,  0.24772212,
        0.20780185,  0.22388151, -0.05069543, -0.14515676, -0.03385801])
>>> pc[0,:]
array([-0.44255435, -0.24050535, -0.17313927,  0.07182494,  0.09748632,
        0.17910516,  0.26125107,  0.71309764,  0.17276004,  0.25095447])
>>> pc.transpose()[0,:]
array([-0.44255435,  0.77430549,  0.14479638, -0.06459874,  0.24772212,
       -0.20780185,  0.22388151, -0.03385801,  0.14515676,  0.05069543])
>>> list(zip(pc.transpose()[:,0], mypca[:,0]))
[(-0.44255435328718207, -0.44255435328718096),
 (-0.24050535133912765, -0.2405053513391287),
 (-0.17313926714559819, -0.17313926714559785),
 (0.07182494253930383, 0.0718249425393035),
 (0.09748631534772645, 0.09748631534772684),
 (0.17910516453826955, 0.17910516453826758),
 (0.2612510722861703, 0.2612510722861689),
 (0.7130976419217306, 0.7130976419217326),
 (0.17276004381786172, 0.17276004381786136),
 (0.25095447415020183, 0.2509544741502009)]
```

Comment: they are not the same, see: 0.20780185 and -0.20780185

Comment: @mourinho see the duplicate question I've flagged, there is a sign ambiguity when performing PCA