# Difference in PCA implementation between numpy only vs sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, pca

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist=input_data.read_data_sets('data/MNIST/', one_hot=True)
```

**numpy implementation**

```
# Entire Data set
Data=np.array(mnist.train.images)
#centering the data
mu_D=np.mean(Data, axis=0)
Data-=mu_D


COV_MA = np.cov(Data, rowvar=False)
eigenvalues, eigenvec=scipy.linalg.eigh(COV_MA, eigvals_only=False)
together = zip(eigenvalues, eigenvec)
together = sorted(together, key=lambda t: t[0], reverse=True)
eigenvalues[:], eigenvec[:] = zip(*together)


n=3
pca_components=eigenvec[:,:n]
print(pca_components.shape)
data_reduced = Data.dot(pca_components)
print(data_reduced.shape)
data_original = np.dot(data_reduced, pca_components.T) # inverse_transform
print(data_original.shape)


plt.imshow(data_original[10].reshape(28,28),cmap='Greys',interpolation='nearest')
```

**sklearn implementation**

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca = PCA(n_components=3)
pca.fit(Data)

data_reduced = np.dot(Data, pca.components_.T) # transform
data_original = np.dot(data_reduced, pca.components_) # inverse_transform
plt.imshow(data_original[10].reshape(28,28),cmap='Greys',interpolation='nearest')
```

I'd like to implement PCA algorithms by using numpy. However I don't know how to reconstruct the images from that and I don't even know if this code is correct.

Actually, when I used `sklearn.decomposition.PCA`, the result is different from the numpy implementation.

Can you explain the differences?

Comment: Where does `only_2` come from?

Comment: Ah sorry, i used only 2 in Mnist, but you can think it as Data. It doesn’t matter.

Comment: @ N EMO: The reason I want to know about `only_2` is to understand if you scaled it, and if so, how you did it?

Comment: Another recent PCA question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52565675/bug-in-scikit-learn-pca-or-in-numpy-eigen-decomposition

Comment: I edited my question for clarity, maybe you guys can understand it better than before.

Comment: I think the biggest difference is that `sklearn` uses an SVD approach by default rather than computing the full covariance structure. So it's unlikely that you'd see exactly the same results, though very similar.

Answer (score 1):

I can spot a few differences already.

For one:

```
n=300
projections = only_2.dot(eigenvec[:,:n])
Xhat = np.dot(projections, eigenvec[:,:n].T)
Xhat += mu_D
plt.imshow(Xhat[5].reshape(28,28),cmap='Greys',interpolation='nearest')
```

The point I'm trying to make is, if my understanding is correct `n = 300`, you are trying to fit 300 eigen vectors whose eigen values go from high to low.

But in `sklearn`

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca = PCA(n_components=1)
pca.fit(only_2)

data_reduced = np.dot(only_2, pca.components_.T) # transform
data_original = np.dot(data_reduced, pca.components_) # invers
```

It seems to me you are fitting just the FIRST component (the component that maximizes variance) and you're not taking all 300.

Further more:

One thing I can clearly, say is that you seem to understand what's happening in PCA but you're having trouble implementing it. Correct me if I'm wrong but:

```
data_reduced = np.dot(only_2, pca.components_.T) # transform
data_original = np.dot(data_reduced, pca.components_) # inverse_transform
```

In this part, you are trying to PROJECT your eigenvectors to your data which is what you should go about doing in PCA, but in `sklearn`, what you should do is the following:

```
 import numpy as np
 from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

 pca = PCA(n_components=300)
 pca.fit_transform(only_2)
```

If you could tell me how you created `only_2`, I can give you a much more specific answer tomorrow.

Here is what `sklearn` says about `fit_transform` for PCA: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.fit_transform:

```
fit_transform(X, y=None)
Fit the model with X and apply the dimensionality reduction on X.

Parameters: 
X : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_features)
Training data, where n_samples is the number of samples and n_features is the number of features.

y : Ignored
Returns:    
X_new : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_components)
```

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, You don't have to focus on only_2 and number of n_components, it was just a mistake. Because i already wrote the algorithms with same n_components and same 'Data' set actually, i am just wondering whether my numpy code is incorrect or not. Thank you for knowing me about pca.fit_transform. By the way, what is the difference between data_reduced and pca.fit_transform? and how to implement reconstruction algorithms in numpy?

Comment: I thought pca.components_ are eigenvectors in sklearn. Are these different?

Comment: @ N EMO: You are correct. And your calculation can only be understood by people who know PCA. Your reconstruction into `data_reduced` is RIGHT. But why not use the inbuilt method?

Comment: Hahaha just a practice. I edited my question more clearly. I hope you would get precise information about my implementation than before.

Comment: @NEMO Please give me a few hours. I will get this done and show you. I have an assignment to submit