# Implementing PCA with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pca

I wanted to implement PCA with a class similar to the one in `sklearn`.

My algorithm for finding PCA with k principal component is as follows:

- Compute the sample mean and translate the dataset so that it's centered around the origin.
- Compute the covariance matrix of the new, translated set.
- Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, sort them in descending order.
- Project the dataset onto the vector space spanned by the first k eigenvectors.

```
import numpy as np


class MyPCA:
    def __init__(self, n_components):
        self.n_components = n_components

    def fit_transform(self, X):
        """
        Assumes observations in X are passed as rows of a numpy array.
        """

        # Translate the dataset so it's centered around 0
        translated_X = X - np.mean(X, axis=0)

        # Calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the covariance matrix
        e_values, e_vectors = np.linalg.eigh(np.cov(translated_X.T))

        # Sort eigenvalues and their eigenvectors in descending order
        e_ind_order = np.flip(e_values.argsort())
        e_values = e_values[e_ind_order]
        e_vectors = e_vectors[e_ind_order]

        # Save the first n_components eigenvectors as principal components
        principal_components = np.take(e_vectors, np.arange(self.n_components), axis=0)

        return np.matmul(translated_X, principal_components.T)
```

However, when run on Iris dataset, this implementation produces vastly different results than sklearn's one, and the results do not show that there are three different groups within the data:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plot_pca_results(pca_class, dataset, plot_title):
    X = dataset.data
    y = dataset.target
    y_names = dataset.target_names

    pca = pca_class(n_components=1)
    B = pca.fit_transform(X)
    B = np.concatenate([B, np.zeros_like(B)], 1)

    scatter = plt.scatter(B[:, 0], B[:, 1], c=y)
    scatter_objects, _ = scatter.legend_elements()
    plt.title(plot_title)
    plt.legend(scatter_objects, y_names, loc="lower left", title="Classes")
    plt.show()


dataset = datasets.load_iris()
plot_pca_results(MyPCA, dataset, "Iris - my PCA")
plot_pca_results(PCA, dataset, "Iris - Sklearn")
```

[image: Results of my PCA]
[image: Intended results]

What might be the cause for such differences? Where is my approach, or my calculations incorrect?

Comment: To normalize the data for PCA, you need not only mean=0 but also stdev=1. Something like `translated_X = (X - np.mean(X, axis=0))/np.std(X, axis=0)`

Comment: @krubo Even after I applied this normalization/z-score, the results are still off.

Answer (score 12):

**Comparing the two methods**

The issue is with not standardizing the data and the extraction of eigen vectors (principal axes). This function compares the two methods.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 

def pca_comparison(X, n_components, labels):
  """X: Standardized dataset, observations on rows
     n_components: dimensionality of the reduced space
     labels: targets, for visualization
  """

  # numpy
  # -----

  # calculate eigen values
  X_cov = np.cov(X.T)
  e_values, e_vectors = np.linalg.eigh(X_cov)

  # Sort eigenvalues and their eigenvectors in descending order
  e_ind_order = np.flip(e_values.argsort())
  e_values = e_values[e_ind_order]
  e_vectors = e_vectors[:, e_ind_order] # note that we have to re-order the columns, not rows

  # now we can project the dataset on to the eigen vectors (principal axes)
  prin_comp_evd = X @ e_vectors

  # sklearn
  # -------

  pca = PCA(n_components=n_components)
  prin_comp_sklearn = pca.fit_transform(X)

  # plotting

  if n_components == 3:
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')
    ax.scatter(prin_comp_sklearn[:, 0],
                  prin_comp_sklearn[:, 1],
                  prin_comp_sklearn[:, 1],
                  c=labels)
    ax.set_title("sklearn plot")

    ax = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')
    ax.scatter(prin_comp_evd[:, 0],
                  prin_comp_evd[:, 1],
                  prin_comp_evd[:, 2],
                  c=labels)
    ax.set_title("PCA using EVD plot")
    fig.suptitle(f"Plots for reducing to {n_components}-D")
    plt.show()

  elif n_components == 2:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
    ax[0].scatter(prin_comp_sklearn[:, 0], 
                prin_comp_sklearn[:, 1],
                c=labels)
    ax[0].set_title("sklearn plot")
    ax[1].scatter(prin_comp_evd[:, 0], 
                prin_comp_evd[:, 1],
                c=labels)
    ax[1].set_title("PCA using EVD plot")
    fig.suptitle(f"Plots for reducing to {n_components}-D")
    plt.show()

  elif n_components == 1:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
    ax[0].scatter(prin_comp_sklearn[:, 0], 
                np.zeros_like(prin_comp_sklearn[:, 0]),
                c=labels)
    ax[0].set_title("sklearn plot")
    ax[1].scatter(prin_comp_evd[:, 0], 
                np.zeros_like(prin_comp_evd[:, 0]),
                c=labels)
    ax[1].set_title("PCA using EVD plot")
    fig.suptitle(f"Plots for reducing to {n_components}-D")
    plt.show()

  return prin_comp_sklearn, prin_comp_evd[:, :n_components]
```

Loading the data set, pre-processing and running the experiment:

```
dataset = datasets.load_iris()

X = dataset.data
mean = np.mean(X, axis=0)

# this was missing in your implementation
std = np.std(X, axis=0)
X_std = (X - mean) / std

for n in [3, 2, 1]:
  pca_comparison(X_std, n, dataset.target)
```

**Results**

[image]
[image]
[image]

3D plot is a bit cluttered, but if you look at the 2D and 1D cases, you'll notice the plots are the same if we multiply the first principal component by -1; scikit-learn PCA implementation uses Singular Value Decomposition under the hood, which will give non-unique solutions ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44847053/5864582)).

*Test:*

Using the `flip_signs()` function from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/240492/100048)

```
def flip_signs(A, B):
    """
    utility function for resolving the sign ambiguity in SVD
    http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/34396/115202
    """
    signs = np.sign(A) * np.sign(B)
    return A, B * signs

for n in [3, 2, 1]:
    sklearn_pca, evd = pca_comparison(X_std, n, dataset.target)
    assert np.allclose(*flip_signs(sklearn_pca, evd))
```

**Issues in your implementation:**

1. If we look at the data scales in the iris data set, the data are of different scales. This suggests that we should standardize the data ([Read here for more](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/62699/100048))

Quoting a part of the above answer:

> Continued by @ttnphns
>
> When would one prefer to do PCA (or factor analysis or other similar type of analysis) on correlations (i.e. on z-standardized variables) instead of doing it on covariances (i.e. on centered variables)?
>
> When the variables are different units of measurement. That's clear
>
> ...

2. In order to obtain the principal axes using `e_values, e_vectors = np.linalg.eigh(X_cov)`, you should extract columns of `e_vectors` ([documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html)). You were extracting rows.

Comment: I think `eigh` comes presorted by eigenvalues

Comment: I also think that we should transpose the eigenvectors in order to make the matrix multiplication during the projection work (in case of strict subset of eigenvectors, it fails the required-dimension match and that gives us a clue that the transpose needs to happen even in the case where there is no principal component reduction.